# Map $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$ onto the open unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G = \mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$. I wan't to find an analytic function $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ where $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the unit disk such that $f$ is onto, and preferably if possible one-to-one.

Now I've seen that $g(z) = \frac{1}{2}(z+1/z)$ maps the open unit disk to $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$ in a one-to-one fashion and therefore the given candidate would be its inverse.

$$g(z) = w\Leftrightarrow z^2-2zw+1 = 0\Leftrightarrow (z-w)^2 = w^2-1.$$

**Here is my problem:** I want to show that $g$ is invertible and find a concrete formula for $g^{-1}$ however I am not sure how to do this using square roots. Say we want to use the square root defined from the branch of the logarithm which satisfies $\log re^{it} = \log r+it$ for $0<t<2\pi$. Then we want $w^2-1$ to stay away from $(-\infty,0]$. However writing $w = x+iy$ it is clear that we then need to restrict $w$ to lie in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Big((-\infty,-1]\cup(1,\infty]\Big)$ which defeats the purpose since we want $w\in \mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$. How should I go about choosing a branch in this case?

---

Clearly $g$ is undefined at $0$ so this only gives a bijective map from $G$ to $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$. Also by simple connectivity injectivity is not possible however can we find a map which is onto?

Comment: A few things to consider, $g$ is not analytic at $z=0$, the open disk is simply connected but $G$ is not.

Comment: Would not $g$ map the origin, $0\in \mathbb{C}$ to the point at infinity?

Comment: yes this is correct I missed this it takes $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$ to $G$. Since one-to-one is not possible could one instead find an onto map from $G$ to $\mathbb{D}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the principal branch of the logarithm (or equivalently the unique square root with positive real part for any complex $z$ that is not a negative real) we can take $G$ to the open right half plane minus $1$ by $\sqrt{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}$. Then using the standard Mobius transform $\frac{w-1}{w+1}$ we continue to the punctured unit disc in a bijective fashion from $G$. But now take a Blaschke product of order $2$ with precisely one zero at the origin, eg $z\frac{z-.5}{1-.5z}$ will do. Since this is a $2:1$ map of the unit disc onto itself, it is then surjective from the punctured unit disc onto the unit disc, hence putting these $3$ together we get a holomorphic map from $G$ onto the unit disc which is locally conformal ( non zero derivative) except at one point (which comes from the unique critical point of the Blaschke product inside the unit disc)

With more care one can actually get a locally conformal map from $G$ onto the unit disc, but it is tricky (though doable) to construct explicit such, though they follow easily from covering theory and using a Blaschke product of order $3$ with distinct critical points.

Comment: How does the result follow "easily" from covering theory (and Blaschke theory) ?

Comment: Using a Blaschke product of order $3$ with two different critical points gives you a locally conformal map from the disc minus two points onto the disc; covering theory gives you a locally conformal map from the unit disc onto the disc minus two points. Putting them together you get a locally conformal map from the unit disc onto itself that is not injective, so you can eliminate a point and still have a locally conformal map now from the disc minus a point onto the disc and the point eliminated can be moved around with a Mobius transform

Comment: Thank you, @Conrad. My nitpick is that I challenge you to take a book on algebraic topology  and find a single theorem that can be used for your proof. The fact that there exists  a locally conformal map from the unit disc onto the disc minus two points" is a very hard theorem in complex analysis **which can be stated in terms of coverings**  but cannot be deduced from what is generally taught in courses on covering theory. Still, your post and your comment are quite interesting: +1.

Answer (score 2):

If $f:G\to \mathbb D$ is onto it cannot be one-to-one: else $G$ and $\mathbb D$ would be analytically isomorphic.
Indeed the inverse of a bijective analytic mapping between open subsets of $\mathbb C$ is automatically analytic.
Note that this is a non trivial result.
But this is absurd since these domains are not even homeomorphic:  $\mathbb D$ is simply-connected whereas $G$ is not.

Comment: . . . . and I suspect the fact tha they are not homeomorphic is easier to show than the "non [hyphen omitted] trivial result" mentioned here, and is plenty to answer that part of the question.

Comment: @Michael: you seem to have missed my point. Of course it is easy to see that $\mathbb D$ and $G$ are not homeomorphic. But how do you prove that an analytic   bijection $f:G\to \mathbb D$ is a homeomorphism without using some non trivial result?

Answer (score 1):

An onto map can be given as follows: $1-\frac{1}{z^2}$ takes $G$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Big((-\infty,0]\cup\{1\}\Big)$. Taking the principal branch of the square root this maps to $\mathrm{Re} z>0$ without the point $1$. So
$$z\mapsto \exp\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}}$$
takes $G$ to $|z|>1$. And therefore
$$\frac{1}{\exp\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}}}$$
takes $G$ onto the unit disk

This is probably not the simplest such map.

Comment: 1 is not in G so this should not be a problem?